# Can I nest classes in standard CSS like in LESS

Tags: css, less

With the LESS preprocessor, you can nest CSS code inside other CSS code, like this:

```
.Element {
    .AnotherElement {
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    .YetAnotherElement {
        background-color: #000;
    }
}
```

This would make the background of `.Element .AnotherElement` white, and it makes `.Element .YetAnotherElement` have a background color of black.  It does it all without writing it out like:

```
.Element .AnotherElement {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.Element .YetAnotherElement {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Does the first example coincide with CSS syntax, or do I have to use the LESS preprocessor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting is a feature of LESS and SASS, not native to CSS.

This is one of the most common uses for CSS preprocessors, but they offer a lot more too.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured as much, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

No, css doesn't support this syntax, in your css example the "Element" and "AnotherElement" will to receive this properties, AnotherElement will not inherit properties of Element.